# Problems with defining heading pitch and roll in 3D-netlogo

Tags: netlogo

i'd like to simulate sun rays on a building. For the angle of the sun rays, i have the right elevation and azimuth angles. I was calculating the corresponding values for heading and pitch. But heading, pitch and roll seem to affect each other. When heading changes, also pitch changes. I have no idea how to calculate the corresponding values to my angles. 
I was checking out the "Turtle and Observer Motion" code example in the netlogo library, but that was no help.

This is my code so far:
angles shall change every 60 ticks (position in the list changes)
lists contain converted heading and pitch values respectevly

```
globals [h  ; heading
  p        ; pitch
   r       ;  roll
   i      ; instead of tick
   data_az    ; a list with the azimuth angles
   data_el    ; a list with the elevation angles
   hour       ; is the position of the angles in the list, stands for the hour
   i_test
   i_round
  ] 
breed [rays ray]
to setup
  ca
  file-open "heading.txt"  
  set data_az file-read
  file-close

  file-open "pitch.txt"   
  set data_el file-read
  file-close
   check-date
    set r 0
  set i 1
  set hour hour - 1 
    set-default-shape rays "line half"
    reset-ticks
end
to go

  tick

   if i = 1440   ; after 24x60 i stop     
  [
    stop
    ]

   set i_test  i / 60              
   set i_round round i_test       



   if i_test = i_round or i = 1   
   [                                
    set hour hour + 1              
       set h item hour data_az
      set p item hour data_el

    ] 



  if h != 0         
       [
         create-sunshine
         run-sunshine
         ]





  set i i + 1

  close

end 
to create-sunshine 

  create-rays 5 [ setxyz random-pxcor max-pycor random-pzcor

      set color yellow
      set heading h
     set pitch p
     set roll r

      set size 2


  ]
end
to run-sunshine
  ask rays [fd 1]
  ask rays  [if pxcor = 0 [die]]  ;rays stop at the edges
  ask rays  [if pxcor = 199 [die]]
 ask rays  [if pycor = 0 [die]]
  ask rays  [if pycor = 49 [die]]
  ask rays  [if pzcor = 0 [die]]
  ask rays  [if pzcor = 199 [die]]
end
to close 
  file-close-all 
end 
to check-date
  if date = "march-equinox" [set hour 0]
  if date = "summer-solstice" [set hour 24]
 if date = "september-equinox" [set hour 48]
  if date = "winter-solstice" [set hour 72]
end
```

looking forward to your recommendations!
thanks in advance
Jana

Comment: Would Face or facexyz be too crude for your model? http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/face3d.html

Comment: as i want rays coming from random x and z coordinates, every ray would have a different angle towards a (facexyz-)point, right? but rays should have the same angle within an hour.. But i could create one ray facing a point and copy it for the other rays, right?

Comment: I think so very clever. They can also facexyz coordinates that don't exist. I.e. facexyz -1000 23456 567760000

Comment: You should answer your question when you get it working. For the next guy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From our discussion

Idea 1 
Have one of the turtles facexyz a point that gives you the correct elevation and azimuth and copying those values for the rest of the turtles. Something like

```
 Ask one-of turtles 
         [
         Facexyz 1000 45663 4663; or something
         Ask other turtles[
                            Set heading [heading] of myself
                             Set pitch [pitch] of myself.   
                              ]
```

]

Idea 2

If roll is set to 0 pitch should equal elevation and heading should equal azimuth.

Answer (score 0):

So it worked with idea 1. Thanks!

This is the code now:

```
globals [x
  y
  z
  data_x
data_y
data_z
hour
i
i_test
   i_round
   leader

]

breed [rays ray]

to setup
  ca
  file-open "x.txt" ; three files are loaded with x y and z coordinates respectevely.
  set data_x file-read
  file-close

  file-open "y.txt"
  set data_y file-read
  file-close

  file-open "z.txt"
  set data_z file-read
  file-close

  set hour hour - 1
  set i 1
  set-default-shape rays "line half"

    reset-ticks
end



to go
  tick
  if i = 1440 [
    stop]

  set i_test i / 60
  set i_round round i_test

  if i_test = i_round or i = 1 [
    set hour hour + 1
    set x item hour data_x
    set y item hour data_y
    set z item hour data_z]

  if i_test = i_round or i = 1 [
  if y != 0 [
    create-leader 
    create-follower
  run-sunshine]]

  set i i + 1
  close

end



to create-leader  
    crt 1 [setxyz x y z 
      facexyz 45 1 45
    set leader who
    ]
  end

to create-follower  
  crt 5 [setxyz random-xcor 70 random-zcor
    set heading [heading] of turtle leader
    set pitch [pitch] of turtle leader
    ]
end

to run-sunshine
  ask turtles [fd 1 
    pendown]

end

to close 
  file-close-all 
end
```